# Nesting async class methods / functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

so this is my code for the class and what i am trying to do with it

```js
const getExternalDbInfo = require('./helperJS/get-external-db-info')
class ExternalDb {
    constructor(extdb_user, extdb_password, extdb_privilege, extdb_ip, extdb_port, extdb_sid) {
        this.extdb_user = extdb_user,
        this.extdb_password = extdb_password,
        this.extdb_privilege = extdb_privilege,
        this.extdb_ip = extdb_ip,
        this.extdb_port = extdb_port,
        this.extdb_sid = extdb_sid
    }
    async getDbData(){
        let data=await getExternalDbInfo(this.extdb_user, this.extdb_password, this.extdb_privilege, this.extdb_ip, 
            this.extdb_port, this.extdb_sid);
        return this;
    }
    async getTablespace(){
        console.log(  getDbData().tablespace_data)
        return  getDbData().tablespace_data

    }
}

const newDb= new ExternalDb("***");

(async function () {
    let x =await newDb.getDbData().getTablespace()
console.log(x)
})();
```

so i am trying to chain to the class methods (getDbData().getTablespace()) so that i don't have to call the external db more than once. but i get following error: **(node:14468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: newDb.getDbData(...).getTablespace is not a function**. Is this even possible or is it something i am not understanding because i am a noob in async programming. *i have tried returning {this, data} for the getDbData() method, but it didn't work*

Comment: even though `return this` normally allows method chaining, it won't in an `async` function because all async functions, by design, return a Promise. So here `getDbData` returns a Promise that resolves to the instance it was called on.

Comment: So, this code isn't making a lot of sense because in `getDBData()`, you don't do anything with the `data` that you retrieve.  So, it won't make any difference if you call `getDbData()` before calling `getTablespace()`.  So, either you're very misguided about what you're trying to do with `await newDb.getDbData().getTablespace()` or the question is missing some actual code here such that your calling sequence would do something useful.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah it didn't make alot sense so i tried  returning {this, data}. It was just poor design and me desperately wanting to chain the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if "nesting" is the right term here, it sounds like you are trying to call the one method from the other. The correct way to do that is

```
class ExternalDb {
    …
    async getDbData(){
        const data = await getExternalDbInfo(this.extdb_user, this.extdb_password, this.extdb_privilege, this.extdb_ip, this.extdb_port, this.extdb_sid);
        return data;
//             ^^^^
    }
    async getTablespace(){
        const data = await this.getDbData();
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        console.log(data);
        return data.tablespace_data;
    }
}
```

You would then not chain anything, but simply call

```
const x = await newDb.getTablespace();
console.log(x);
```